# Mock another method in SWF Workflow Client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, junit, mockito, amazon-swf

I am trying to write a unit test for a AWS SWF workflow. Below is the code I would like to Test

```
@Override
public void execute(String abc) {
    new TryCatch() {

        @Override
        protected void doTry() throws Throwable {
            Promise<SomeObject> temp = activityClient.action(abc);
            again(temp, abc);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doCatch(Throwable e) throws Throwable {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };
}


@Asynchronous
public void again(Promise<SomeObject> someObject, String abc) {
    // Do Something   
}
```

My Test class is as below:

```
public class SomeWorkflowTest extends AbstractTestCase {

    @Rule
    public WorkflowTest workflowTest = new WorkflowTest();

    List<String> trace;
    private SomeWorkflowClientFactory workflowFactory = new SomeWorkflowClientFactoryImpl();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        trace = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Register activity implementation to be used during test run
        SomeActivitiesImpl activitiesImpl = new SomeActivitiesImpl() {

        @Override
        public SomeObject performHostRecovery(String abc) {
            trace.add("ABC: " + abc);
            SomeObject testObject = new SomeObject();
            return testObject;
        }
    };
    workflowTest.addActivitiesImplementation(activitiesImpl);
    workflowTest.addWorkflowImplementationType(SomeWorkflowImpl.class);
}

@Test
public void testWorkflowExecutionCall() throws Throwable {

            SomeWorkflowClient workflow = workflowFactory.getClient("XZY");
     workflow.execute("XYZ");

    List<String> expected = new ArrayList<String>();
    expected.add("ABC: abc");

    AsyncAssert.assertEqualsWaitFor("Wrong Wrong", expected, trace, null);
}
```

}

I have used [SWF Testing Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/test.html#test.junit) to write above test class. However the method that I am testing (execute()) is invoking another method in same class. I am not concerned with the execution of internal method and would like to mock it out, but given the way the workflow class object is instantiated, I am not clear on how to mock the inner method.

Can someone please point out on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You actually can instantiate a workflow object or any other object that workflow uses inside the test method:

```
@Test
public void testWorkflowExecutionCall() throws Throwable {
   SomeWorkflow workflow = new SimpleWorkflow(...);
   workflow.execute("XYZ");

   List<String> expected = new ArrayList<String>();
   expected.add("ABC: abc");

   AsyncAssert.assertEqualsWaitFor("Wrong Wrong", expected,  trace, null);
}
```

It works because WorkflowTest executes test methods in the context of a dummy test workflow. The code

```
 SomeWorkflowClient workflow = workflowFactory.getClient("XZY");
 workflow.execute("XYZ");
```

actually creates a child workflow in the context of this dummy workflow. But nothing prevents you from executing any async code directly without creating the child workflow.